# How to resize table cell based on textview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITextView` in a custom `UITableViewCell`. The textview delegate is assigned in the tableviewcell custom class. Textview scrolling is disabled. Text loads into each textview and is multiline. But the text is always clipped because the cell height doesn't change.

I have the following in `viewDidLoad` of the tableview controller:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 56.0 
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: So you need to work with your constrain.

Comment: i just give you one link at put place i use label and you can now use your textview and give same constrain that i give in that link and try it so your problem will be solve .

Comment: if is there possible then update your question with your tableview screen storyboard and Runtime .

Comment: tell me that which version of swift you use for this project ?

Answer (score 2):

**Try my answer its work perfectly.**

```
var record : NSArray = NSArray()
var  hight: CGFloat = 0.0
```

**Put this code in viewDidLoad()**

```
record = ["I have a UITextView in a custom UITableViewCell. The textview delegate is assigned in the tableviewcell custom class." ,"Textview scrolling is disabled. Text loads into each textview and is multiline. But the text is always clipped because the cell height doesn't change.","I have the following in viewDidLoad of the tableview controller:"," have a UITextView in a custom UITableViewCell. The textview delegate is assigned in the tableviewcell custom class.","Textview scrolling is disabled. Text loads into each textview and is multiline. But the text is always clipped because the cell height doesn't change.","I have the following in viewDidLoad of the tableview controller:","i just give you one link at put place i use label and you can now use your textview and give same constrain that i give in that link and try it so your problem will be solve","I have the following in viewDidLoad of the tableview controller:"];

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return record.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Textviewcell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let textview: UITextView = (cell.viewWithTag(5) as! UITextView)

    textview.text = record.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // 7.1>
   hight = self.findHeightForText(self.record.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String, havingWidth: self.view.frame.size.width - 10, andFont: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)).height
   return 44 + hight
}



func findHeightForText(text: String, havingWidth widthValue: CGFloat, andFont font: UIFont) -> CGSize {

    var size = CGSizeZero
    if text.isEmpty == false {
        let frame = text.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFloat.max), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
        size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, ceil(frame.size.height))
        }
        return size
}
```

**In Swift 3.0**

```
func findHeightForText(text: String, havingWidth widthValue: CGFloat, andFont font: UIFont) -> CGSize {

        var size = CGSize.zero 
        if text.isEmpty == false {
            let frame = text.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: widthValue, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
            size = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: ceil(frame.size.height))//CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, ceil(frame.size.height))
        }
        return size
    }
```

Here are some screen shot .**Storyboard**

[image]

**Runtime tableview with UITextView**

[image]

Comment: @4thSpace you will not mention in your question which language you use objective c or swift . so tell me that and my answer is correct i just create one demo for you . and i upload its with screen shot.

Comment: Obviously Swift. No one uses Objective-C unless they are forced to. Looking forward to your updated answer.

Comment: @4thSpace give me some time i will convert my whole code for swift and i just update my answer as soon as possible

Comment: downvote because of Objective-C. I'll update the vote once the new answer is posted.

Comment: @4thSpace now check it . in swift

Comment: Ton of errors. I'll have to downvote again unless you can fix them. CGSizeZero and CGSizeMake unavailable in Swift. You obviously didn't test this at all.

Comment: @4thSpace CGSizeZero and CGSizeMake is available in Swift 2.0 and in Swift 3.0 you can use with CGSize and CGRect.

Comment: @4thSpace you can also not specify that which version you use in swift .

Answer (score -2):

You should use the delegate method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to set the height for the row. Then, inside that method, return the height that the cell should be by calculating the height of the textview which will occupy the space. You should use the function:

```
-(CGFloat)heightForTextViewRectWithWidth:(CGFloat)width andText:(NSString *)text withBuffer:(float)buffer
{
    UIFont * font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFontName" size:15.0f]; // Replace with your font name and size
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};

    // this returns us the size of the text for a rect but assumes 0, 0 origin, width is the width of that your text box will occupy. 
    // Ex. If you text box has padding of 12 both trailing and leading to the cell, then width should be the cell's width minus 24.
    CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT)
                                 options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                              attributes:attributes
                                 context:nil];

    // return height of rect
    return rect.size.height;
}
```

This will determine the rect that your text view will occupy in the cell. The height that is returned is equal to the height of the text view, so if you want the cell to be taller than the text box, add that padding.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString * yourText = commentDict.text; // or however you are getting the text
    float widthPadding = 24.0f;
    float heightPadding = 16.0f;
    float height = [self heightForTextViewRectWithWidth: (tableView.frame.size.width - widthPadding) andText:yourText];
    return height + heightPadding;

}
```

Hope this helped!