# Dynamically resizing an IOS tableview cells which have a textview embedded in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, textview, row-height

I have tried the following code which gives the correct textview frame height

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

    myToDoList[keyArray[sect]]![row] = textView.text
    var frame = textView.frame
    frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height
    textView.frame = frame
    print(frame)

    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForView(textView)
    print(inputActive,indexPath)

    self.tableView.indexPathForView(inputActive)
    self.tableView.rowHeight = frame.size.height
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40035858/6656894 Refer this answer

Answer (score 3):

The answer from "Krunal" is missing a piece or two...

Start with the cell layout / constraints:

[image]

And use this code:

```
import UIKit

class WithTextViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var theTextView: UITextView!

    var callBack: ((UITextView) -> ())?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // in case these were not set in IB
        theTextView.delegate = self
        theTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        // tell controller the text changed
        callBack?(textView)
    }

}

class TableWithTextViewTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var cellData = [
        "UITableViewController implements the following behaviors:",
        "If a nib file is specified via the init(nibName:bundle:) method (which is declared by the superclass UIViewController), UITableViewController loads the table view archived in the nib file. Otherwise, it creates an unconfigured UITableView object with the correct dimensions and autoresize mask. You can access this view through the tableView property.",
        "If a nib file containing the table view is loaded, the data source and delegate become those objects defined in the nib file (if any). If no nib file is specified or if the nib file defines no data source or delegate, UITableViewController sets the data source and the delegate of the table view to self.",
        "When the table view is about to appear the first time it’s loaded, the table-view controller reloads the table view’s data. It also clears its selection (with or without animation, depending on the request) every time the table view is displayed. The UITableViewController class implements this in the superclass method viewWillAppear(_:). You can disable this behavior by changing the value in the clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear property.",
        "When the table view has appeared, the controller flashes the table view’s scroll indicators. The UITableViewController class implements this in the superclass method viewDidAppear(_:).",
        "It implements the superclass method setEditing(_:animated:) so that if a user taps an Edit|Done button in the navigation bar, the controller toggles the edit mode of the table.",
        "You create a custom subclass of UITableViewController for each table view that you want to manage. When you initialize the controller in init(style:), you must specify the style of the table view (plain or grouped) that the controller is to manage. Because the initially created table view is without table dimensions (that is, number of sections and number of rows per section) or content, the table view’s data source and delegate—that is, the UITableViewController object itself—must provide the table dimensions, the cell content, and any desired configurations (as usual). You may override loadView() or any other superclass method, but if you do be sure to invoke the superclass implementation of the method, usually as the first method call.",
        ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WithTextViewCell", for: indexPath) as! WithTextViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.theTextView.text = cellData[indexPath.row]

        cell.callBack = {
            textView in
            // update data source
            self.cellData[indexPath.row] = textView.text
            // tell table view we're starting layout updates
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            // get current content offset
            var scOffset = tableView.contentOffset
            // get current text view height
            let tvHeight = textView.frame.size.height
            // telll text view to size itself
            textView.sizeToFit()
            // get the difference between previous height and new height (if word-wrap or newline change)
            let yDiff = textView.frame.size.height - tvHeight
            // adjust content offset
            scOffset.y += yDiff
            // update table content offset so edit caret is not covered by keyboard
            tableView.contentOffset = scOffset
            // tell table view to apply layout updates
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

The "key" parts:

1. Add a "call back" closure to your cell, so we can tell the controller when the text has changed.
2. When the call back occurs, have the table view controller: update the dataSource with the edited text; tell the text view to resize itself; and adjust the content offset to avoid having the caret (the text insertion point) disappear behind the keyboard.

Comment: Excellent thanks - the only changes I made was so I could use a ViewController ISO a TableViewController.
Other than that it works perfectly.
I just need to add the code to scroll the table up for the keyboard but I have code for that

Answer (score 0):

Set `UITextview` height according to your content (text) size using `sizeToFit` and enable `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

**Try this and see**

```
class TextViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textview: UITextView!


    func adjustTextViewHeight(textview : UITextView) {
        textview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        textview.sizeToFit()
        textview.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
}


class TableController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Don't forget to set dataSource and delegate for table
        table.dataSource = self
        table.delegate = self

        // Set automatic dimensions for row height
        table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }



    // UITableViewAutomaticDimension calculates height of label contents/text
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textview") as! TextViewCell
        cell.adjustTextViewHeight(textview: cell.textview)
        return cell
    }

}
```

Here is Storyboard Layout:

[image]

And here is result:

[image]

Comment: That looks right - will post after trying - the only thing I have different is that I have a number of sections but that should not matter.

Comment: I copied your example and the rows adjust to the size of the text already in the textview but does not adjust to a change in the text content on the fly.
I have used textviews out off tables in  got them to expand according to content - just can't get it right in a tableview.

Comment: What does sort of work is table.reloadData() but thats not a solution.
So really all that is required is that when the contents exceeds the textview frame size  then table.reloadData() . The obvious problem is the keyboard is lowered each time so its not the right solution

Answer (score -1):

Its very easy to implement dynamic cell height when you design cell with interfaceBuilder directly as prototype cell or xib, where you just need to set top an bottom constraints properly and rest of the thing is done by tableViewAutoDimension.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
  tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

[image: Desingning cell for auto dimension]

Comment: Oh okay will this work with a textview that will have rows of data added by the user?

Comment: @JeremyAndrews if you using with textview then its working fine. try once if any issue then put comment .

Comment: Will try need to design a cell - will post outcome

Comment: For textView it is designed in such a way that whenever the content entered by the user exceeds the height of textView then the content starts to scroll so there might not be change on the fly in the cell height. If you display the content in the label with number of lines set to 0 then the size of cell will definately change. Still try it and share your findings.