# UITextView inside tableview not resizing according to content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have a tableView and a UITextView inside it. I am trying to add data from JSON to the table view but it is not shrinking/expanding according to size. I have tried a lot of forums and methods.

The main problem is - if it starts expanding/shrinking with height, it stops shrinking/expanding and vice versa. Bot height and width are not working.

**This is because, when I set the trailing and leading constraints of the UITextView to the cell, it starts working with height but stops working with width. When I remove the leading/trailing constraints, the content of the UITextView goes beyond the screen and does not come as multiline i.e. does not expand with height.** I have tried -

[How do I size a UITextView to its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content)

[How to resize table cell based on textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034506/how-to-resize-table-cell-based-on-textview)

and a lot many like these.

A little of my code-

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Message") as! TextViewCell
    cell.customTextView.textColor = UIColor.white

    // Give a source to table view cell's label
    cell.customTextView.text = requestResponseArr[indexPath.row]
    cell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    cell.sizeToFit()        

    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        cell.customTextView.backgroundColor = ConstantsChatBot.Colors.iMessageGreen
        cell.customTextView.textAlignment = .right
    } else {
        cell.customTextView.backgroundColor = ConstantsChatBot.Colors.ButtonBlueColor
        cell.customTextView.textAlignment = .left
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

And in viewDidLoad()-

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    // RandomEstimatedRowHeight
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
}
```

I do not want the textview to be editable. Please reply with swift as I am not familiar with Objective C. Thanks

EDIT: Custom cell code

```
class TextViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var customTextView: UITextView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    customTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

Comment: Also why don’t you use a `UILabel` with numberOfLines = 0 instead of `UITextView`.

Comment: I want the link, phone numbers etc. detections and also some other stuff

Comment: can you notice one thing in second link given by you , check its heightForRowMethod -- They are Providing 44 + Height of TextView that is to make cell to grow bigger so it cover the bounds of TextView, Automatic dimension fails in such case , I too had faced this to make it happen exactly need to provide a height value as they had given

Comment: Looks like you are setting the constraints on the storyboard. Make sure constraints you add Top, Bottom, Leading and Trailing constraints.

Comment: yes, they are top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints

Comment: Use UILabel instead of UITextView or if it required to use UITextView  for scroll then u need set fixed height of UITextView.

Comment: I need height and width. I need the width to shrink if the text is smaller than screen width. I have both but individually. They are not coming together. For more clarity, check my comments on this answer of this post only. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49293512/8279637

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried with `UITextView` inside `UITableViewCell`.

**Constraints**

`UITextView`, top, bottom and right as 2, 2 and 5, Width as 50. `Font Size` as 13, `Alignment` as Center. Give `Outlet connection` for `Width constraints` as `txtVwWidthConst`

**UIViewController**

```
@IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
var textWidthHeightDict = [Int : CGSize]()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    stringValue = [0 : "qwer\nasdasfasdf", 1 : "qwe", 2 : "123123\nasdas\nwqe", 3 : "q\n3\n4", 4 : "klsdfjlsdhfjkhdjkshfjadhskfjhdjksfhkdjsahfjksdhfkhsdfhjksdfjkasklsdfjlsdhfjkhdjkshfjadhskfjhdjksfhkdjsahfjksdhfkhsdfhjksdfjkasklsdfjlsdhfjkhdjkshfjadhskfjhdjksfhkdjsahfjksdhfkhsdfhjksdfjkas"]

    for i in 0..<stringValue.count
    {
        GettingTextViewSize(getStr: stringValue[i]!, fontSize: 14, loopValue: i)
    }
    tblView.reloadData()
}

func GettingTextViewSize(getStr : String, fontSize: CGFloat, loopValue : Int)
{
    var textSize = (getStr as! NSString).size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)])
    if textSize.width > self.tblView.frame.width
    {
        // IF STRING WIDTH GREATER THAN TABLEVIEW WIDTH
        let multipleValue = textSize.width / self.tblView.frame.width
        textSize.height = (textSize.height * (multipleValue + 1.0))
        textSize.width = self.tblView.frame.width

        textWidthHeightDict[loopValue] = textSize
    }
    else
    {
        textSize.height = textSize.height + 10 //ADDING EXTRA SPACE
        textSize.width = textSize.width + 10 //ADDING EXTRA SPACE

        textWidthHeightDict[loopValue] = textSize
    }
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return stringValue.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "table", for: indexPath) as! TblTableViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = cellBGColr[indexPath.row]

    cell.txtVw.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    cell.txtVw.text = stringValue[indexPath.row]
    cell.txtVw.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.txtVwWidthConst.constant = (textWidthHeightDict[indexPath.row]?.width)!
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var heightVal = (textWidthHeightDict[indexPath.row])
    return heightVal!.height + 8 //ADDING EXTRA SPACE
}
```

**UITableViewCell**

```
class TblTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var txtVw: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtVwWidthConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
    // TEXTVIEW WIDTH CONSTRAINTS    


    override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Note**

`UITextView` only, we have to calculate String size. But, in `UILabel`, this concept is very simple. Let me know, if you have any queries.

Answer (score 1):

Disable UITextView `isScrollEnabled` is `false` inside `cellForRowAt`

[Demo Example](https://github.com/paresh1994/TextViewInsideTableView)

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable `UItextView` Scrolling for that.

```
textView.isScrollingEnabled = false
```

and in the cell add top, bottom, right and left constraints of textview.
And add height constraint >= 10

[image]

Comment: That is already there in the code above. Check out the custom cell. Also its disabled via the storyboard as well.

Comment: @Aman : can you add height consriant >= 10 of textview and check?

Comment: It is fixing the hight to a constant value and the text is getting trimmed in height because of the fixed constant

Comment: Changing it to >= has no effect and the UIText if i do it with constraints. If I removed leading and trailing constraints, the text becomes single lined

Comment: calculate the size of the text and set the height constraint to UITextView.

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal The height works even just with leading, trailing ... constraints. But then the width shrinking and expanding does not work.

Comment: Manage width according to your requirement make relation with adjacent views or make with superview width

Answer (score 0):

You need to set all four constraints for textview i.e. leading, trailing, top and bottom lets say all are set to 8 from margin.

It will look something like below:
[image]

check demo on GitHub [here](https://github.com/vanitaladkat/DemoTextViewInCell/tree/master)

Comment: Yes, this I already have. But when I have this, I lose flexible width property as I have set the constraints to all 4 sides. I want the width to be flexible according to content inside. For example, in the picture you posted, the first cell has "some text" in it. But the cell is expanding to full screen width. I want the cell to expand just to the width of the text.

Comment: And when I remove the 4 constraints on 4 sides, I get the width issue fixed but the height issue starts and the UITextView becomes single lined, and goes out of screen.